# Misspelled words in Waton conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation

How to handle misspelled words in Watson conversation API. NLP technique/Algorithm used in converation API calculates the word ranking and matches the trained data based on the rank.But how to handle the mispelled words or the short names in english.

Comment: Lol, is the title supposed to be ironic?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is nothing special to handle misspellings. The best process is to use the 'Synonyms' option within entities to add what you expect the user to use, including misspellings, short names, and acronym's.